# Format json with CodeiGniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter php, I need to make an api rest that returns an array containing the books models, to do this I created a file inside the controller called api2.php here I entered the return of the rest call in post, so api2.php call. the problem is that the json returning from the call is not formatted correctly should be in another format.

**Json Now(incorrect):** https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/8b41fe97896380e64b5df1f92f99b954

**Correct json:**

```
{  
  [
     id: "2", 
     desc: "sss",
     ..
  ],
  [ 
      id: "3", 
     desc: "sss",
     ..

   ], 

}
```

**Controllers/Api2.php:**

```
<?php

class Api2 extends CI_Controller {
    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Book_model');
    }


    function index() {

        header('Content-Type: application/json');      
        $values = $this->Book_model->get_all_books();
        $book_list = [];
        
            foreach ($values as $row)
            {
                
                $book_list[$row['id']] = $row['id'];
                $book_list[$row['cat']] = $row['cat'];
                $book_list[$row['descrizione']] = $row['descrizione'];
                $book_list[$row['titolo']] = $row['titolo'];
                $book_list[$row['prezzo']] = $row['prezzo'];
                $book_list[$row['autore']] = $row['autore'];
                $book_list[$row['order']] = $row['order'];
            }
            echo json_encode($book_list);

        }
}
```

**Models/Book_model.php:**

```
<?php

class Book_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    /*
     * Get book by id
     */
    function get_book($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('books',array('id'=>$id))->row_array();
    }
        
    /*
     * Get all books
     */
    public function get_all_books()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get('books')->result_array();
    }
    

    /*
     * function to add new book
     */
    function add_book($params)
    {
        $this->db->insert('books',$params);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    
    /*
     * function to update book
     */
    function update_book($id,$params)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('books',$params);
    }
    
    /*
     * function to delete book
     */
    function delete_book($id)
    {
        return $this->db->delete('books',array('id'=>$id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Output` class to echo json content

```
function index() {
   $values = $this->Book_model->get_all_books();
   $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($values));
}
```

Comment: with your solution i have this error: https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/8e8aad202c8d05633d113fc380a8343e

Comment: this is my array now but is incorrent. gist.github.com/riccardopirani/5229f1e2a68e1cc753faf268edadab46 –

Comment: @riki, I don't know what you mean. My method echoes out the contents of the API call directly. Your previous `index()` function had errors and can be reduced to what I posted. What is that link you just sent? Also,  your initial error has something to do with `installHook.js` which is not addressed in your question.

Comment: @riki -  can you show me the code that is generating the error? (the view file) I know what the issue is but need to see that page

Comment: No error read above, json is not format correctly

Comment: @riki - pls see my updated answer. Try it - changing both the Model and the Controller code just as I have put in my answer. Let me know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: ok then, can you please show how you're trying to access the data? Show the part of your `view` file that grabs the data. The issue with the JSON you posted is it doens't have any keys - all the keys are identical to the values. After I fixed that by directly outputting the result_array() you said the error was an unidentified index which led me to think you were trying to access an object instead of array. Seeing the view file will clear this up. Pls show in your question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that it expects a result of object that has prop called *renderers* but its undefined, so you have to declare it here if you don't have experience of debugging js code and change the expected results accordingly:

```
$values = $this->Book_model->get_all_books();

$this->output->set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode(["renderers" => $values]));
```

Comment: make sure that you have a correct response, access the page iteself from the broweser of from network tab from developer tools and see what you got there.

Comment: with your solution i have this error: https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/8e8aad202c8d05633d113fc380a8343e

Comment: @riki but this is a PHP error `Undefined index: desc at line numner 30 in file controllers/Api2.php` has nothing to do with the rest

Comment: this is my array now but is incorrent. https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/5229f1e2a68e1cc753faf268edadab46

Comment: with your solution i have blank page

Answer (score 0):

Parse the data into an array  and process it as json

```
function index() {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        //print link element
        /*$array = array(
            "foo" => "bar",
            "bar" => "foo",
        );*/
        $values = $this->Book_model->get_all_books();
        book_list = [];
        
            foreach ($values as $row)
            {
                $book_list[$row['id']] = $row['id'];
                $book_list[$row['desc']] = $row['desc'];
            }
           return $book_list;
           echo json_encode($book_list);
    }
```

Comment: with your solution i have this error: https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/8e8aad202c8d05633d113fc380a8343e

Comment: this is my array now but is incorrent. gist.github.com/riccardopirani/5229f1e2a68e1cc753faf268edadab46 –

Comment: Correct your array to  the name of column. $book_list[$row['id']] = $row['id'];
  $book_list[$row['cat']] = $row['cat'];

Comment: i have try your but this is result json: https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/8b41fe97896380e64b5df1f92f99b954 but json is incorrect